Colouring polygons based on point layer in QGIS
I have the following layers:

One Vector Polygon Layer with Protected Areas (several variables, e.g. "NAME" of the Protected Area)
One Vector Point Layer with coordinates, pesticide names etc. and the risk factor
Intersect Layer: I got a new vector point layer with all the points in the protected areas with the intersect tool. Here, of course, the variables of the former point layer and the protected areas layer are included in the attributes table.

I want to colour all protected areas, that contain at least one point to illustrate which Protected Areas are at specific risk. I tried to use the join feature (Polygon Layer and Point Layer as Join Layer), but then all the joined variables from the point layer are NULLs. I don't know what to do else.
It would also be cool to colour the Protected Areas with a gradient based on the number of points they contain, but I would be happy if I could somehow colour them at all.

I'm looking for the processing tools (or any other option) to be able to colour my protected areas based on either (Yes/No: have points in them) or based on the number of points (pesticide) located within them (Gradient)

Thank you, that is what I need - the only problem is that I have several measurements at one specific location (e.g. 18 for different pesticides), but it only counted as one point - is there a possibility to change?

I think it is be possible "Join attributes by location (summary) tool" , right?

Thank you! Now I encountered another problem. When I use "Join attributes by location (summary) tool" I get a higher number of counts than I have points in my Point Layer. The reason is that in my Protected Areas Layer, several Protected Areas overlap/are nested within each other. I tried to use the dissolve (by variable NAME or ID) and the union tool, but the issue is still there. Is there another tool or way to fix that?

In the attribute table, there is also a variable called "IUCN_Cat) (IUCN Categories for Protected Areas). I tried to filter out all that do not have such a category, however, now I am missing a lot of Protected Areas, as many are also reported as a value of "Not Reported". Additionally, they are still nested within each other (but of course a bit less). Any ideas?

Let's assume there are point and polygon layers, see the image below. Both are in the EPSG:5348. As was specified in the comment polygon features could also contain enclaved territory.

Step 1. Apply the "Union" tool.
Leave the overlay layer [optional] empty.

Step 2. Proceed with the "Delete duplicate geometries" tool.
Step 3. Continue with the "Count points in polygon" tool and get the following output:

To colour polygon features with a gradient based on the number of points they contain, check the 3.3. Lesson: Classification. So, in the end, you may end up with a similar result.


Thanks for the answer. I tried the union tool, however, I got the following error: Feature could not be written to Union_ffa15542_5a33_48f5_a6b2_251dec1e5287: Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon
I use this Shapefile for the Protected Areas (I filtered out all marine protected areas to only have terrestrial ones): https://www.protectedplanet.net/en/country/FRA

The Union tool is pointless in terms of (Multi)LineSrings geometries; you will need to filter geometries

Thank you first of all for all your help and answers! I'm confused as the source states it's a polygon file and also the information of the layer says "Geometry: Multipolygon" - What do you mean by filter geometries? Is my plan even possible with this source layer? I mean the visualisation works, but it is a bit messy of course
